# Fastest way to select rows where value of column of strings is in a set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `set` of email addresses that I've selected from one set of values. I'd like to subset a `pandas DataFrame` to include only rows where the `unique_id` column value is not contained in the set. Here's what I've done that is running very slow:

```
signup_emails = set(online_signup.unique_id)
non_email_signup_event_emails = event_attendees[event_attendees.unique_id.apply(lambda x: x in signup_emails) == False].email
```

The table is several hundred thousand rows, but my computer just freezes up on this command, shows a high CPU load, and doesn't terminate even after long waits (20 minutes). How can I do this faster?

Comment: try this: `event_attendees.ix[~event_attendees.unique_id.isin(online_signup.unique_id), 'email']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `isin` method.

```
event_attendees[event_attendees.isin(signup_emails)]
```

For not in the signup_emails, you can do

```
event_attendees[event_attendees.isin(signup_emails) == False]
```